# Domain config panel confusion

Tags: dns

I registered domain name recently and i'm confusing about how to set up it. My hosting provider told to set domain A record to IP address they gave to me.

In domain config panel, there are records A, AAAA. Also there is value "@" in field that is like prefix for domain name. 
What is A, AAAA, "@"? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

As an option you can use `dig` or any other online tool for [dns lookup](https://domain-records-lookup.com/). A means address record, and AAAA ipv6 address record.